# ERROR when passing parameters in url to DELETE function in http server python

Tags: python, http, url, server

I have this method:

```
def do_DELETE(self, id):
```

And I try to pass parameters to it using the following code:

```
par = {"id": "1234"}
f = requests.delete('http://localhost:8080/delete', params = par1)
```

And I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\...\src\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\...\src\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 449, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "C:\...\src\venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 444, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 1349, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 316, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 285, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
(*And 2 more similar errors here*)
```

what am I doing wrong? How to pass parameters correctly?

Comment: What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: I edited the question and added part of the error message, not everything can be attached, if necessary I will try to replay with the full error.

Comment: are you able to call the request via another client like postman using the same URL and the same params? btw: prob. just a typo:you are defining par but giving par1 into delete. You let out some parts of the error. Do the other errors also have error messages? If so you should show them